# Select2 won't work (render) after ajax page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, pageload

I have page that use `select2` plugin:

```
$(function() {
    if($('.su-tech').length) {
        $('.su-tech').select2({
            allowClear: true,
            width: '100%'
        });
    }
});
```

and html code like this:

```
<select class="select2 su-tech" style="width:100%;">                                                    
    <option value="1" >option1</option>
    <option value="2" >option2</option>
    <option value="3" >option3</option>
</select>
```

also I use ajax to load html content with jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#page1", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/example-page1",
        success: function (result) {
            $('.ajax_content').html(result);
        },
    })
})
```

with this condition my `select2` doesn't render and won't work. how to render plugins with ajax content load.

Comment: in `success` of `ajax` again initialize `select2`

Comment: is your `select` lie inside the `.ajax_content` ?

Comment: select2 is sample. I have many plugins that have this problem. such as x-editable, ckeditor, ...

Comment: my select locate in result and dynamically add to page

Comment: Really great answer. It worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are recreating the DOM inside the `.ajax_content`. To fix this you can create a `initialize` function and add code for all the controls that are need to be initialize on DOM ready like below

```
function Initialize()
{
    if($('.su-tech').length) {
            $('.su-tech').select2({
                allowClear: true,
                width: '100%'
            });
    }
}
```

and then call this function on success of every Ajax request like below

```
$(document).on("click", "#page1", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/example-page1",
        success: function (result) {
            $('.ajax_content').html(result);
            Initialize(); // after the HTML update
        },
    })
})
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: There is no more efficient solution? I think this solution decreases load speed

Comment: It depends how you are using events delegation inside `Initialize` function. You can optimize by choosing optimum `selector` while selecting the DOM objects. Or try reducing the size of HTML update by ajax request.

Comment: Really Nice. Great answer. Thanks for your answer.